# Trying to import CSV file to Analysis Services Tabular project

Tags: ssas-tabular

I have Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2019 and Access database engine both 64-bit installed on my machine and was trying to import a CSV file to Analysis Services Tabular project. However keep getting the error message shown below.

"Failed to save modifications to the server. Error returned: 'OLE DB or ODBC error: The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file 'BatchInfo.csv'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view and write its data.; 3051."

Any help is appreciated please.

Answer (score 0):

Either you or someone else has the file open. Sometimes you have to completely close out of the program that created the file, or the last program used to read, write, or save the file.

If it's something on your computer, you may be able to find what has it opened with the [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) tool. Install it, and then use **Find > Find Handle or DLL...** and search on "BatchInfo.csv".

[image: Searching with Process Explorer]